# Google sheets "array_agg"... or equivalent? (join aggregation)

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

Currently, I have this

```
=QUERY(
  QUERY(
    'Raw Paste'!C2:E, "select C, count(C) where C is not null group by C order by C label count(C) ''"
  ), "WHERE Col2 >= 2")
```

The second `QUERY()` is so I can filter the aggregate function like an SQL `HAVING` function...

That will do this:

[image]

What I want to do though is next to the count, I want a 3rd column that joins the invoice numbers that are included in the aggregate.

This would be trivial with `ARRAY_AGG(C)` but google sheets ain't that fancy.

I've considered maybe using `INDEX`/`MATCH` somehow but I dunno.. I need to join the strings together where an item appears more than once.

```
C    D
111  PPP
222  OOO
222  QQQ
```

The output I want:

```
C    D
222  OOO, QQQ
```

Comment: I can do this in one formula with the query if you'll share an (editable) sample sheet of some sort..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM({QUERY(QUERY(C:D, 
 "select C,count(C) where C is not null group by C pivot D", 0), "select Col1 offset 1", 0),
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(ISNUMBER(QUERY(QUERY(C:D, 
 "select count(C) where C is not null group by C pivot D", 0), "offset 1", 0)), 
 QUERY(QUERY(C:D, 
 "select count(C) where C is not null group by C pivot D", 0), "limit 0", 1)&",", ))
 ,,999^99))}), ",$", ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: wow thats wild. Can you explain what the performance gains are (just for my knowledge)

Comment: well, for starters its just a one formula instead 1000x per row

Answer (score 3):

It can be done by using `FILTER` and `JOIN`

```
=IFERROR(JOIN(", ", FILTER(D2:D, C2:C = A3)))
```

`FILTER` will look in `C2:C` for `A2` and return the values from `D2:D`, which get passed to `JOIN`

Comment: there is a better solution if you also have value in A3

Comment: If you want to post it i will mark it as the answer. I'll be doing this for many many rows

Comment: @player0 the rows its searching will be tens of thousands of lines long so performance might be nice